# pygame.error: Can't seek in this data source

Tags: python, pygame

Hi guys I am receiving the following error;

```
pygame.error: Can't seek in this data source
```

The traceback is as follows;

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Source Code/Python/graphicalSlotMachine/Main.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Main:
  File "F:/Source Code/Python/graphicalSlotMachine/Main.py", line 7, in Main
    fruity = Machine.fruitMachine()
  File "F:\Source Code\Python\graphicalSlotMachine\net\Toby\GSM\Machine.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.splash()
  File "F:\Source Code\Python\graphicalSlotMachine\net\Toby\GSM\Machine.py", line 68, in splash
    self.fruitMachine()
  File "F:\Source Code\Python\graphicalSlotMachine\net\Toby\GSM\Machine.py", line 121, in fruitMachine
    chris = Fruit.Fruit(reelGroup3, 3, random.randint(1, 4))
  File "F:\Source Code\Python\graphicalSlotMachine\net\Toby\GSM\Fruit.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.image = pygame.image.load(self.picture).convert_alpha()
pygame.error: Can't seek in this data source
```

and the line which causes the code is;

```
 self.image = pygame.image.load(self.picture).convert_alpha()
```

Comment: What is the value of `self.picture`?

Comment: self.picture = ResourceLoader.imageOne which in turn is pygame.image.load(self.imageOne) with the imageone being a file path to an image.

Comment: `self.picture` must be 'corrupted' in some way, that's the only thing that makes sense.  Try to do `print(self.picture)` somewhere.

Comment: You don't know how to distinguish your objects and their types. You're basically trying to load an already loaded image.

Comment: @Viron: Glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are loading an already loaded image as indicated by your comment above:

```
self.picture = pygame.image.load(self.imageOne)
self.image = pygame.image.load(self.picture)
```

Please distinguish your strings from your image handler, don't what's been loaded .